# MySql Insert error from node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a MySQL table like this:

[image]

Below is my code from where I am trying to insert data into mysql table:

```
var data = {
    id          : 1,
    custname    : input.custname,
    custemail   : input.custemail,
    ordertype   : input.ordertype,
    noorder     : input.noorder,
    orderdate   : input.orderdate
};

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO order SET ?', data,      function(err,rows) {
    if (err)
        console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

    res.render('createorder', {title :"Order Created Successfully"});
});
```

But is giving me the following error:

```
INSERT INTO order SET `id` = 1, `custname` = 's', `custemail` = 's@gmail.com', `ordertype` = 'Chalbhaja', `noorder` = 2, `orderdate` = '2015-07-24T16:07:58.684Z'
Error inserting : Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order SET `id` = 1, `custname` = 's', `custemail` = 's@gmail.com', `ordertype` =' at line 1
```

Comment: Looks like your using node-mysql.  You should probably set each column individually within your mysql query, ie custname = ?.  I've never tried using the library this way.

Comment: I saw lot of example in this way. But it is not working for me

Comment: can you console.log(query.sql) and run that sql manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order` word is a keyword in MySQL. It is possible to have a table named `order` though. You just have to escape it in your query, like this:

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO `order` SET ?', data, function(err,rows) {
    if (err)
        console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

    res.render('createorder', {title :"Order Created Successfully"});
});
```